# Nextjs <Image /> component not working with img src file name with non English characters

Tags: reactjs, next.js

When using  component from NextJs it is working good as expected, only when file names are in English.
for example this code is working good:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
<Image alt="shark image" src="/images/shark.png" width={1000} height={1000} />
```

But when providing a src with filename that contain Hebrew letters the image is not loading, for example:

```
import Image from 'next/image';
<Image alt="shark image" src="/images/כריש.png" width={1000} height={1000} />
```

and the following error is shown:

```
error - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Content-Disposition"]
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:3)
at setResponseHeaders (..\node_modules\next\dist\server\image-optimizer.js:442:13)
```

with network response of

```
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Should be fixed by [PR#30287](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/30287).

Comment: Voting to close this question as it is a known issue whose fix has been initiated. Until it makes its way to a release, we can't do much here at StackOverflow.

Comment: There is no temporal fix I can use?